# Non-surgical ways of removing ichor

Tags: acne, removal, cystic-acne, abscess-lesions

I have a pretty nasty form of acne, and some of the abscesses are so deep it takes weeks for them to even become removable, though for the whole time they cause pain and/or discomfort.
What I am curous about - are there ways to somehow dissolve the ichor accumulated in abscess when it is under skin?